# How to Join N live MP3 streams into one using FFMPEG?

Tags: c++, c, mp3, ffmpeg, live

How to Join N live MP3 streams (radio streams like such live KCDX mp3 stream http://mp3.kcdx.com:8000/stream
) into 1 using FFMPEG? (I have N incoming live mp3 streams I want to join them and stream out 1 live mp3 stream) I mean I want to mix sounds like thay N speakers speak at the same time (btw N stereo to 1 mono), please help.

BTW: My problem is  mainly how to make FFMPEG read from stream not from file...
Would you mind giving some code examples, please.

Comment: Can you define join? Do you mean overlap the sounds of each or concatenate the mp3 so that the resulting is the length of the sum of all lengths?

Comment: duplicate by the same author : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533401/ffmpeg-how-to-work-with-infinite-live-streams

Comment: no dup - this is Q in certan - that one is in general

Comment: mix sounds like thay speak at the same time

Comment: ok.. I delited that one genefal Q... Happy?)

Comment: All streams must be decoded to the same PCM, mixed and encoded to MP3. In general you need: MP3 decoding engine, resampler, mixer, MP3 encoding engine. Saying roughly this is not too complicate task, but I do not know, how to implement this using FFMPEG (I am not familiar closely with FFMPEG).

Comment: My problem is  mainly how to make FFMPEG read from stream not from file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `url_fopen()`, defined in avio.h, is the function you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, example would be highly appreciated. I can't figure it out.